# Нужна помощь в орфографии!

Tags: орфография

Очень прошу помочь филологов! Интересует слитное или раздельно написание "(не)обязательно" и "(так)же".

Способы, эффективные с одними, необязательно также хорошо работают с другими.

Спасибо!

Comment: Инна, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

"Необязательно" пишется слитно, т.к. нет противопоставления и специальных слов-"магнитов" .  "Так же" в данном случае пишется раздельно. Частицу "же" можно убрать или перенести в другую часть предложения, и смысл не изменится.